# What is the Loop Invariant in the following code

Tags: loops, conditional-statements, invariants, loop-invariant

What is the Loop Invariant(s) in this sample code.
This is an excerpt code implemented in C programming language:

```
//pre-condition m,n >= 0
x=m;
y=n;
z=0;
while(x!=0){
  if(x%2==0){
    x=x/2;
    y=2*y;
  }
  else{
    x=x-1;
    z=z+y;
  }
}//post-condition z=mn
```

These are my initial answers (Loop Invariant):

1. `y>=n`
2. `x<=m`
3. `z>=0`

I am still unsure about this. Thanks.

Comment: None of your answers is even fulfilled before the loop.

Comment: You can format your code by selecting it and clicking the `{}` button.

Comment: @Howard Sir, I already fixed/updated my initial answers. How about it?

Answer (score 2):

Your answers are indeed invariant but say little about the conditions of your loop. You always have to look for specific invariants. In this case it is quite easy since there are only two (exclusive) operations inside your loop.

The first `x' = x/2; y' = 2*y;` looks like it is invariant under `x*y`.

The second `x' = x-1; z' = z+y;` is not: `x'*y' = x*y - y`. But if you add `z` again it will be invariant. `z'+x'*y' = z + y + x*y - y = z+x*y`.

Fortunately also the first condition is invariant under `z+x*y` and thus we have found a loop invariant.

- pre-condition: `z+x*y = m*n`
- post-condition: `x=0` (loop condition) and therefore we can deduce from our invariant: `z = m*n`

Comment: Thanks. But I'd like to ask on how you come up with z+x*y = m*n (as a pre-condition)? Where did m*n came from?

Comment: @Miciah Amberong The invariant is `z+x*y` and the initial values for `x`, `y` and `z` are given in your code.